# modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Tags: java

Выдает ошибку:

> Illegal static declaration in inner class Employee.EmployeeTest
>   modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

```
public class Employee {

    int id;
    String surname;
    int age;
    double salary;
    String department;

    public Employee(int id, String surname, int age, double salary, String department){
       this.id=id;
       this.surname=surname;
       this.age=age;
       this.salary=salary;
       this.department=department;       
    }



    class EmployeeTest{
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            Employee e1= new Employee(1, "Vasin", 23, 235.4, "dep1");
            Employee e2= new Employee(2, "Petin", 40, 417.6, "dep2");
       }       
    }
}
```

Делаю в NetBeans 8.0.2.

Скажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вложенный класс (и, соответственно, его методы) в Java имеет смысл только в контексте объекта родительского класса. Чтобы оторвать вложенный класс от этого контекста, нужно объявить сам этот вложенный класс как `static`.

```
...

  static class EmployeeTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "Vasin", 23, 235.4, "dep1");
        Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "Petin", 40, 417.6, "dep2");
    }       
  }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Comment: да, добавление `static` помогло.  
но странно, что в видеоуроке, который смотрю, работало без этого добавления...